# isometry tag description?

Tags: discussion, tagging

So,  I saw a few different definitions of the term "Isometry" when I was searching for help on my most recent problem.   Not finding anything online here or elsewhere, I went ahead and posted a question here.   So I used [banach-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banach-spaces), then I noticed there was an [isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isometry) tag with [no description](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/isometry/info)...

Can someone with more knowledge than I add a description?  I would, but I'm just starting functional analysis and am not 100% sure on whether it requires $\Vert Tx\Vert=\Vert x\Vert$ or like in my case that $\Vert T(x)-T(y)\Vert=\Vert x-y\Vert$ (The distinction necessary when T is not linear)

Comment: A fairly general definition of isometry is a map from one metric space to another that preserves distances.  So on a normed space it would mean $\|T(x)-T(y)\|=\|x-y\|$, which for a linear map is equivalent to preserving the norm.  Then there are local isometries on Riemannian manifolds, which perhaps should be included.

Comment: How about we just nuke the tag instead of trying to define it?

Comment: @Fundamental I think this is the best course of action. There's no sense in making tags for specific kinds of operators.

Comment: Nuking is fine with me too,  just didn't seem right to have an undefined tag.